# Open file with or without extension

Tags: perl

This is how I open a file in Perl:

```
open FILE, "</file.ext";
```

How do I open the file `file` regardless of if it's called `file` or `file.ext` in Perl?

Comment: What happens if both `file` and `file.ext` exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Errno qw( ENOENT );

my ($file) = grep { -f $_ } qw(file file.ext)
   or die $!=ENOENT;
open my $fh, '<', $file
   or die "$file: $!";
```

Comment: I think I'd take a similar approach, but might do it via a ternary, e.g. `open ( my $input, '<', -f $file ? $file : $file.".ext" ) or die $!; `.

Answer (score 3):

The following will produce the most usable error message:

```
sub open_if_exists {
   my ($qfn) = @_;

   my $fh;
   open($fh, '<', $qfn)
      and return $fh;

   $!{ENOENT}
      and return undef;

   die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");
}

my $qfn = "file";
my $fh = open_if_exists($qfn) || open_if_exists("$qfn.ext")
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn\" or \"$qfn.ext\": $!\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

`open` returns 0 on failure, so you can chain open calls together with the `||` or `or` operators.

```
my $fh;
open ($fh, '<', 'file') ||
    open ($fh, '<', 'file.ext') ||
    open ($fh, '<', $other_default_filename) ||
    die "Couldn't find any acceptable file: $!";
```

Comment: That can die with the wrong error message. For example, it will die with `No such file or directory` if you don't have permissions to read `file` and `file.ext` doesn't exist. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach is to pass the filename to the piece of the code that needs to open the file:

```
sub f {
   my ($filename) = @_; 

   open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "$!";
   # do things with $fh
   close $fh;

   return;
}
```

now it doesn't matter what the name of the file is, function `f` will open it (assuming it exists and you have permissions to read it):

```
f('file');
f('file.ext');
```

You could also pass the filename as a command-line argument:

```
#!perl 

# test-open.pl
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $filename = shift @ARGV or die "Missing filename";
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "$!";
```

now you call test-open.pl, passing it a filename:

```
perl test-open.pl file
perl test-open.pl file.ext
```

Comment: Can I return the open file so I can do the manipulation outside the function? I need to iterate over it multiple times.